# Console.log only ever shows the original state, even though I'm 100% sure the state is being updated in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, state, console.log

My app has state that is a 2d array filled with 0s. As I run the app, 2d array is traversed and those 0s are changed to 1s as the traversal occurs. This is reflected on the screen, as the grid cell changes color from clear to blue when it changes from 0 to 1.

So basically what I'm saying is that I can see that the state is updating. If I look at the components tab in the dev tools my state reflects that as well. So, here comes my problem:

When I console.log the state, the only thing I ever see is the ORIGINAL state filled with 0s. The grid traversal is executing on a loop, so every second I can see that state is changing, but every loop the console.log does not change.

I've read other questions on here about react state updates being asynchronous, and people try to log the new state before it is done updating. But that does not seem to be my problem, because I am literally 100% sure that state has updated, as confirmed by the visual in my browser as well as in the dev tools.

Here is a link to the github repo with my code: https://github.com/jeffpalmeri/graph-traversal/blob/master/src/App.js

Any ideas why this is happening?

The console.log I'm referring to is on line 121.

Comment: you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have something to do with your reference and when you open the console and watch it.

Ex.

You have a array `a=[1,2,3]`, the reference to this `a` is not changed during the printout, so at this second it's `1,2,3` and next second it'll be `2,3,4`. In the end it'll be stable as `3,4,5`.

If you open the console tab in the last minute, i think you'll see everything is `3,4,5`. Unless during the print out, you do

```
  console.log(a.slice())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `useCallback` hook. The React documentation says:

> useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Since you don't specify any dependencies, your callback will never change and will always print the same value of `grid` due to closure (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). In addition, you are calling your callback within your callback using `setTimout`. Since your callback never changes, it will always refer to the initial callback even if you would specify dependencies, again due to closure.

If you want to do something with your `grid` state after it has been updated, use `useEffect` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)